# How to show Image Preview using javascript or jquery in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to show the image preview in Internet Explorer.

I'm using FileReader() it working fine all the browsers but not in ie(version 9) and lower versions.

I need the alternative for FileReader to diplay the preview.

```
    $('#FileUpload').live('change', function () {
            var result = checkFileType();
            alert(result);
            var fileList = this.files;
            var file = fileList[0];
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = function () {
                var binimage1 = r.result;
                // binimage1 = binimage.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');

                //var imag = "<img " + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64," + binimage + "' style='width:100px'/>";

                //  var src = $('#prevImage').attr("src").replace("../../images/nologo.gif", image);


                $('#prevImage').attr("src", binimage1);
                //                    $("#partial1").html(imag);

            };
            r.readAsDataURL(file);
            // r.readAsBinaryString(file);

            //r.readAsDataURL(file);

        });
```

Comment: FileReader API is available in IE10. http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: Please add a version of IE you tested!

Answer (score 0):

FileReader isn't available until IE 10 (http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader). For older IEs you should probably look into Flash based solution to get similar access to user local files.